# Parser for 32-bit and 64-bit Mach-O binary/executable formats in C++

Tags: c++, macos, mach-o

I'm looking for a C++ library that can parse 32-bit and 64-bit Mach-O binary format. I don't need anything fancy, just a disassembly and splitting the file into its sections, so no decompilation, name demangling and so on.

I know I can either rip open any existing disassembler or craft my own binary parsers using the format specification from Apple, but I was kind of hoping not having to go that far, especially if someone else has done the work for me.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with the open-source class-dump tool (http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/). It can read both 32 and 64 bits Mach-o binaries, and is known to have a decent parser.

Answer (score 5):

Try playing around with the command-line tool `otool`; it sounds like it does what you want. You could call it from C code with `system()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [MachOView](http://machoview.sourceforge.net/)
It is still in developing stage, but hopefully becomes a powerful tool soon.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Darwin (Mac OS X kernel) source code, I guarantee somewhere in there they've got a parser for Mach-O binaries.

Comment: It'd be better to read the source to the disassembler.

http://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-750/otool/

Not quite a library, though.